# Getting Exception when download Wagtail

Tags: python, django, wagtail

An exception is displayed on my terminal when attempting to install `wagtail`using command:

```
pip install wagtail
```

This is returned:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip/basecommand.py", line 215, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip/commands/install.py", line 342, in run
    prefix=options.prefix_path,
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip/req/req_set.py", line 784, in install
    **kwargs
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip/req/req_install.py", line 851, in install
    self.move_wheel_files(self.source_dir, root=root, prefix=prefix)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip/req/req_install.py", line 1064, in move_wheel_files
    isolated=self.isolated,
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip/wheel.py", line 345, in move_wheel_files
    clobber(source, lib_dir, True)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip/wheel.py", line 323, in clobber
    shutil.copyfile(srcfile, destfile)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/shutil.py", line 83, in copyfile
    with open(dst, 'wb') as fdst:
IOError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/OleFileIO_PL.py
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer is right there for you to see:

```
IOError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/OleFileIO_PL.py
```

It looks like you're trying to install into the global site-packages directory (on a Mac), for which you do not have write permissions.

`sudo pip install wagtail` would do the trick, but I would advice against that.

I would strongly suggest you employ a [python virtual environment](https://encrypted.google.com/search?q=python%20virtual%20environment%20mac) for each python project you do.

Also, is there a particular reason you're starting a new project with python2 instead of python3?